# Purpose of ForeignKeyConstraint.AcceptRejectRule in ADO.Net?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

What is the purpose in life of the [AcceptRejectRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.foreignkeyconstraint.acceptrejectrule.aspx) property of ForeignKeyConstraint class in ADO.Net?

The MSDN Document doesn't carry sufficient explanation (for me) to make its purpose clear. After reading the documentation, I thought that setting the property to None will prevent cascading of any changes from the parent table to the child table. But, this assumption was proved to be wrong after running the following code:

```
       DataTable table1 = new DataTable("Customers");

        table1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CustomerID", typeof(int)));
        table1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CustomerName", typeof(string)));

        DataTable table2 = new DataTable("Orders");
        table2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("OrderID", typeof(int)));
        table2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CustomerID", typeof(int)));

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataSet.Tables.AddRange(new DataTable[] { table1, table2 });
        dataSet.EnforceConstraints = true;

        DataRelation dataRelation = new DataRelation("CustomerOrders", table1.Columns["CustomerID"],
            table2.Columns["CustomerID"], true);
        dataSet.Relations.Add(dataRelation);

        Debug.WriteLine("No. of constaints in the child table = {0}", table2.Constraints.Count);

        dataRelation.ChildKeyConstraint.AcceptRejectRule = AcceptRejectRule.None;
        dataRelation.ChildKeyConstraint.DeleteRule = Rule.Cascade;
        dataRelation.ChildKeyConstraint.UpdateRule = Rule.Cascade;

        table1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 11, "ABC" });
        table1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 12, "XYZ" });

        table2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 51, 12 });
        table2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 52, 11 });
        table2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 53, 11 });

        table1.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
        table1.AcceptChanges();
        table2.AcceptChanges();

        Debug.WriteLine("No of rows in the parent table = {0}", table1.Rows.Count);
        Debug.WriteLine("No of rows in the child table = {0}", table2.Rows.Count);
```

The output of the above code is:

**No. of constaints in the child table = 1 

No of rows in the parent table = 1 

No of rows in the child table = 1**

Thanks, 
Dinesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid cascading, you need to set `DeleteRule` and `UpdateRule` to `Rule.None`.

I'm not certain but I believe `AcceptRejectRule` only affects whether the accept/reject command itself is cascaded or not. In your code, I would guess that the changes have been cascaded (since that's how `DeleteRule` and `UpdateRule` have been set) but only the changes on `table1` have been accepted; the changes on `table2` have *not* been accepted.

Comment: I invoked AcceptChanges() on table2 as well, and the  output remained the same i.e. 2 related rows get deleted from the child table. I am afraid I am still not able to understand the purpose of this property. Could you please elaborate on "AcceptRejectRule only affects whether the accept/reject command itself is cascaded or not. In your code" ?

Comment: They are being deleted because `DeleteRule = Rule.Cascade`. Try setting `DeleteRule = Rule.None` instead.

Comment: On setting DeleteRule = Rule.None and then running the program, I get the error : "Cannot delete this row because constraints are enforced on relation CustomerOrders, and deleting this row will strand child rows." This is fine, and it is on expected lines; but, it doesn't make clear the purpose of the AcceptRejectRule property.

Comment: @DineshBajaj With `DeleteRule = Rule.Cascade` and `AcceptRejectRule = AcceptRejectRule.None` and calling `AcceptChanges` on table1 only, are the deletes that were cascaded to table2 accepted or not? Does this change when `AcceptRejectRule = AcceptRejectRule.Cascade`?

Comment: Setting either possible values (cascade or none) to the AcceptRejectRule property doesn't make any difference, and on calling AcceptChanges() on table1 only (with DeleteRule set to Rule.Cascade), the related rows from the child table are get deleted.

Comment: @DineshBajaj Okay, it sounds like my understanding of this property is wrong then. Your experiments seem to suggest that you can ignore this property - it works the same either way, and in both cases, how you want it to work.

Comment: Thanks. That is also my understanding of this property as of now.

Comment: deleted rows, are not actually deleting. they're just marked to be deleted. and can reject any time. acceptrejectrule to control accepting or rejecting from parent to cascade to child table. if you set to none, when you accept parent table. child table won't be affected and still can be reject any time after that. (but may cause exception error because of constraint)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding.  Let's say you have a parent child relationship and you set the `relation.acceptrejectrule` to cascade. You also have the `dataadapter.acceptchangesduringupdate` set to `true`,  if you modify the parent and child record and then do a `dataadapter.update` on the parent first, the parent AND child records get "accepted" and if you do a `subsequent dataadapter.update` on the child records nothing will get updated (cause the "accept" was cascaded from parent to child records).  So your parent got updated but not the child records. Possible solutions would be update the child recs first, then the parent, or simply set the `relation.acceptrejectrule` to none. By doing that the "accept" will not cascade down to the child recs and you will be able to update them.  When you do an update on the child recs they, too, will be "accepted" because you have the `dataadapter.acceptchangesduringupdate` set to `true`. Of course, you can set `acceptchangesduringupdate` to `false` and do a `manual dataset.acceptchanges` to accept all the changes in the dataset.  But if you do this, make sure you have done updates on all tables in the dataset.

I'm only stating here what I think is happening based on my testing. If anybody else knows differently please jump in.